# Use NSManagedObject as normal class instance

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

So we have:

```
@objc(Profile)
class Profile: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var firstName: String
}
```

If we try to initialise the class like below and assign some values:

```
var profile = Profile()
profile.firstName = "Test"
```

We get the error:

```
CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initialiser on NSManagedObject class 'xxx.ProfileDto'
```

However when we try to initialise the same class with a NSManagedObjectContext, initialisation and saving is successful.

Comment: That's how it is. It is [*documented*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/index.html) that instances of NSManagedObject subclasses *must* be created with the designated initializer. What answer do you expect?

Comment: You can't. Your NSManagedObject must be contained inside of a NSManagedObjectContext